# Save input value in session and then print variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

is it possible to pass the value of an input with session? i need to pass the value 25 and then save to session

Ej:

Blade.php:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="idevento" value="25">
```

Controller:

```
 session(['variableName' => $request->input("idevento")]);
```

Then I get the value with:

```
$save_value = Session::get('variableName');
```

the problem is that it does not save the value, help pls

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#storing-data ?

Answer (score 0):

**For store session value you would use:**

```
Session::put('variableName', $request->input("idevento"));
```

**To get the variable, you would use:**

```
Session::get('variableName');
```

Comment: Please mark as verified if its help for you. @jerex

Comment: thanks for the help, but I keep getting NULL value

Comment: the input must be inside a <form> for it to work and save the value of the input in session?

Answer (score -1):

i use $variable=Session::get('variableName'); but prints the conten of variableName instead save it into $variable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).